# OpenCL SDK for Intel Project at Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, opencl

Actually I am on my way to write my first OpenCL program. As I have seen in many tutorials that in visual Studio I have to configure properties and add "additional Include directory", most of the tutorials are for nVIdia and Amd so according to them they have to add `$(CUDA_INC_PATH)` and `$(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\include`. But what am I suppose to add for INTEL? [`CUDA_INC_PATH` is not in system path variable so I am going out of clue!]

Comment: I have never had to add any such things even to raw command line gcc, usually going -lOpenCL (link to OpenCL library) will automatically add the right include paths and libraries. But for VS it might be different.

Comment: Can I use gcc from windows? :S

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [Intel SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk)? After that I would look for libraries and headers in its location. Then you can create env. variable or simply add the whole path to include directories in VS.

Comment: I have installed Intel SDK. Then how can I create a env? can you please tell in more detail?

Comment: If you want to create env. vars look on this one: [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/). Still you need to find the location of Intel include directory (with headers) and library directory (with .libs), which will be values of newly created system variables.

Comment: I agree with Geralt. I installed Intel SDK, and INTELOCLSDKROOT exists the location that you indicate. However, I have no idea how to find the location of Intel include directory (with headers) and lib directory(libs). Would you please give a hint for that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Intel SDK it should create an environmental variable called INTELOCLSDKROOT.  To see it click on start, right click on computer.  Click advanced settings settings.  Click on environmental variables.

You only need one SDK to develop with.  The Nvidia SDK one only supports OpenCL 1.1 and does not include the cl.hpp C++ bindings.  I had problems running on the non-AMD devices with the AMD SDK.  The Intel SDK works on Intel, Nvidia, and AMD for me.